# In javafx loading FXML file from another package and error appear?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, fxml

I am facing problem in loading fxml file from different packge.

**Project Structure**
[image: This is a image of my project and packges]

My class that loads the FXML file PlayArea.java looks like this:

```
package controller;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author badar
 */
public class PlayArea extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/gui/FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

My fxml file that is FXMLDocument.fxml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXDrawer?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXHamburger?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>

<BorderPane fx:id="boderpane" minHeight="600.0" minWidth="600.0" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="600.0"  xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controller.FXMLDocumentController">
   <left>
      <JFXDrawer fx:id="drawer" defaultDrawerSize="200.0" prefHeight="503.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </left>
   <top>
      <HBox nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" style="-fx-background-color: #42A5F5;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <JFXHamburger fx:id="hamburger" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </top>
</BorderPane>
```

**Edit:**

*Error Message:*

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/home/badar/Documents/GitHub/DSA%20Lab%20Tasks/Playe%20Area/bin/gui/FXMLDocument.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at controller.PlayArea.start(PlayArea.java:22)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$49(GtkApplication.java:139)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at controller.FXMLDocumentController.initialize(FXMLDocumentController.java:65)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    ... 17 more
Exception running application controller.PlayArea
```

Comment: What is the error exactually? Can you include the log message? Assuming the file couldn't be found, have you tried `"gui/FXMLDocument.fxml"` as path String?

Comment: Probably it's an issue with eclipse not including the fxml file in the class path, but it could also be an issue with the controller class, which is impossible to tell, unless you post error message + the stack trace.

Comment: @fabian please include the log

Comment: @n247s I added the error message.

Comment: @fabian I include the error message

Comment: Sorry I didn't attach first time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with your this line

```
  Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/gui/FXMLDocument.fxml"));
```

just replace it with

```
  Parent root = `FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../gui/FXMLDocument.fxml"));`
```

if you still get the error then
create a file outsite of your packages i.e. in src folder say **Main.class**

now use this

`FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("gui/FXMLDocument.fxml"));`

Comment: The problem still on this line.

Comment: First time when I used all .fxml and .java file in only 1 package it was working fine. But when i want to separate in packages it's not working. :(

Comment: Thank you Sir! I realize my problem.

Comment: @Sudo, glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the controller in the fxml file itself if you're right click and open the file you will find properties and there you will have a tag called controller and you can type the exact folder path .

FXML EG

```xml
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="javafxapplication.FXMLController">

</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: How does this differ from the fxml in the question? The `fx:controller` ***attribute*** is specified there too and it seems to use the correct ***fully qualified class name*** of the controller class.

Comment: @Rahul  Please read my question again! I already did this thing in FXMLDocument.fxml but the problem is it's not working when I try to in different packages.

Answer (score 1):

Updating the previous answer

Here is what tried and it is working fine

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Main.fxml"));
                Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 275);            
                stage.setTitle("FXML Welcome");
                stage.setScene(scene);
                stage.show();
```

[image: My Test Project Structure]

Hope this Solves the Query

Answer (score 0):

I had to change 2 lines to properly open FXML file from controller located in another packet:

```
root = loader.load(Main.class.getResource("document.fxml").openStream());
scene.getStylesheets().add(Main.class.getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
```

Instead of getClass(), there is Main.class .